# Using optocouplers and programmable resistors to control a gamepad

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, opto-isolator

Let me preface by saying that I'm a C developer by trade, with very little electronics/hardware design knowledge.

I started working on a project to map Keyboard/Mouse to a USB HID gamepad with the idea of connecting it to a PlayStation 5. Originally I thought this would be mostly a software solution by creating a USB gadget gamepad device. But alas the PS5 locks down peripherals hard and it only recognizes the PS5 controller and other Sony licensed gamepads. I'm sure it would be possible to reverse engineer the USB packets and figure out how to emulate a full PS5 controller, but that is a large tedious task that is likely to break with future controller/PS5 software updates anyway.

My other idea is to open up an existing PS5 controller and wire up all the buttons and analog sticks and control them with Arduino (or Raspi) GPIOs. My thinking is that if I can get this working it would be a future-proof solution, that will not break with PS5 software changes. The PS5 console itself would also be electrically isolated from my hackery because the PS5 gamepad would connect over Bluetooth in this case.

The PS5 controller has 15 2-state buttons (on/off). and 6 analog axis (4 for analog sticks, and 2 for trigger buttons). There is also a touchpad but I don't want to bother with that.

My current thinking based on browsing around is that I could use 15 optocouplers for the buttons, and 6 programmable variable resistors for the analog axis. I'm sure I have more questions than I know, but lets start with:

Does that sound at all viable?

Can an Arduino or Raspberry Pi (3/4/zero) handle this many parts? It seems there might be enough GPIOs (especially on raspi), and if not I could wire up a couple boards and have them sync up over uart or some other method. But how about power consumption of that many optocouplers?

The optocouplers would entirely isolate the Arduino from the gamepad which sounds great. How about programmable variable resistors for the analog axis? Would those work in this project? I'm thinking of something like https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/AD5220BNZ100

Is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I see little reason to use optocouplers in this case. Digital potentiometer IC's should work for the analog problem. Parts recommendations (shopping questions) are against site policy.

Comment: What would you use instead of optocouplers here? Some kind of relay?

Comment: Yes, it should work. However depending on how the buttons and pots are interfaced to the existing controller chip, you may not need the optocouplers or digital pots. I suggest first tracing the relevant parts of the game controller circuit to get a partial schematic, then measure voltages on buttons and pots as they are operated to see what signals the Arduino needs to produce (and save the Raspberry Pi for something it is more suited to!).

Comment: I'm envisioning this as two entirely separate circuits with their own power supplies. If I interface directly with the chip wouldn't I need common ground?

Comment: @Dafu, is a common ground problematic for some reason ?

Comment: @Unimportant I'm very new to this, my gut feeling was that a common ground would a) add noise to the system b) possibly blow out one of the boards. Sounds like that shouldn't be the case? Thankfully I have some sacrificial hardware to try this on.

Comment: @Dafu There's no reason a common ground would blow up boards if you do it right. Noise, perhaps a bit if you use long cables between both boards, which you shouldn't.